# Problem sending request from react to node in virtual box Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu-18.04

I have a website written on the react + node stack, everything is working fine locally, but when I uploaded the code to the virtual machine, I noticed that a prefix, the root url of my frontend, began to be added to all my requests. I checked that the requests themselves are formed correctly and the paths remain the same. With what it can be connected?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your path should have protocol and host, otherwise it considered as relative and added to proto+hostname.

Change from `185.251.91.117:5000/...` to `http://185.251.91.117:5000/...` and it will stay same.

Can use only relative part of path - `/api/auth/registration`, better idea since port or hostname can change.